sparkR.conf() causing error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) in Databricks Notebook
I am trying to dynamically assign values to a SQL variable using sparkR.conf in a databricks notebook and I am getting the following error when I try to do so.
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) :
Some( Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn):  )
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn):
Note that this does not occur every time that I call the function sparkR.conf(). Rather, it specifically happens for these couple of variables. Any insight as to why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.
The following code runs with no errors:
my_str <- "a, b, c, d"
sparkR.conf("test", my_str)

However, this code gives me the Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) issue:
my_dt <- 20230101
sparkR.conf("dt", my_dt)

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Do all the ones it's failing on have numeric values rather than string/character values?

@MrFlick yes, however, I have tried making my_dt a character value as well and it produces the same error

@MrFlick upon additional investigation, it looks like sparkR.conf() only works with string/character values
